# VPN - What type

Tags: networking, vpn, linux-networking

I am looking at 2 VPN scenarios, but I do not understand the difference between the two.

1. There is a VPN-Server (OpenVPN or IPSec) where some notebooks are connected. I want to access the other notebooks (e.g. IP 10.0.1.10) but I want to keep my current network settings (my ISP IP, & DNS etc.) meaning I want to use the VPN-Network only to get access to some "internal" recources.
2. I want to do the same, but use the VPN-Servers IP-Address to access the internet (use the VPN's network settings)

I figured out how `2.` works, but not how `1.` works. What do I call these 2 scenarios and where should I start digging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're talking about a split tunnel.

The big difference is that with a single tunnel, your default gateway is set to the other side of the VPN link. This means that *all* of your traffic traverses the VPN and is generally considered the most secure, but most bandwidth intensive, approach.

A split tunnel keeps your default gateway on your LAN and puts a static route in place for traffic that needs to traverse the VPN. This allows you to still have access to resources on your own network while also having access to internal resources on the VPN side. Because of this, it is more convenient but generally considered less secure.

To configure `1.` just don't push the route over the VPN as the default gateway, push it as a static route.